# how to implement splice_read for a character device file with uncached DMA buffer

Tags: linux, character, driver, splice

I have a character device driver. It includes a 4MB coherent DMA buffer. The buffer is implemented as a ring buffer. I also implemente the splice_read call for the driver to improve the performance. But this implementation does not work well. Below is the using example:
  (1)splice the 16 pages of device buffer data to a pipefd[1]. (the DMA buffer is managed as in page unit).
  (2)splice the pipefd[0] to the socket.
  (3)the receiving side (tcp client) receives the data, and then check the correctness.
I found that the tcp client got errors. The splice_read implementation is show below (I steal it from the vmsplice implementation):

```
/* splice related functions */
static void rdma_ring_pipe_buf_release(struct pipe_inode_info *pipe,
                struct pipe_buffer *buf)
{
    put_page(buf->page);
    buf->flags &= ~PIPE_BUF_FLAG_LRU;
}

void rdma_ring_spd_release_page(struct splice_pipe_desc *spd, unsigned int i)
{
    put_page(spd->pages[i]);
}

static const struct pipe_buf_operations rdma_ring_page_pipe_buf_ops = {
    .can_merge = 0,
    .map = generic_pipe_buf_map,
    .unmap = generic_pipe_buf_unmap,
    .confirm = generic_pipe_buf_confirm,
    .release = rdma_ring_pipe_buf_release,
    .steal = generic_pipe_buf_steal,
    .get = generic_pipe_buf_get,
};

/* in order to simplify the caller work, the parameter meanings of ppos, len
 * has been changed to adapt the internal ring buffer of the driver. The ppos
 * indicate wich page is refferred(shoud start from 1, as the csr page are
 * not allowed to do the splice), The len indicate how many pages are  needed.
 * Also, we constrain that maximum page number for each splice shoud not
 * exceed 16 pages, if else, a EINVAL will return. If a high speed device
 * need a more big page number, it can rework this routing. The off is also
 * used to return the total bytes shoud be transferred, use can compare it
 * with the return value to determint whether all bytes has been transfered.
 */
static ssize_t do_rdma_ring_splice_read(struct file *in, loff_t *ppos,
           struct pipe_inode_info *pipe, size_t len,
           unsigned int flags)
{
    struct rdma_ring *priv = to_rdma_ring(in->private_data);
    struct rdma_ring_buf *data_buf;
    struct rdma_ring_dstatus *dsta_buf;
    struct page *pages[PIPE_DEF_BUFFERS];
    struct partial_page partial[PIPE_DEF_BUFFERS];
    ssize_t total_sz = 0, error;
    int i;
    unsigned offset;

    struct splice_pipe_desc spd = {
        .pages = pages,
        .partial = partial,
        .nr_pages_max = PIPE_DEF_BUFFERS,
        .flags = flags,
        .ops = &rdma_ring_page_pipe_buf_ops,
        .spd_release = rdma_ring_spd_release_page,
    };

    /* init the spd, currently we omit the packet header, if a control
     * is needed, it may be implemented by define a control variable in
     * the device struct */
    spd.nr_pages = len;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        offset = (unsigned)(*ppos) + i;
        data_buf = get_buf(priv, offset);
        dsta_buf = get_dsta_buf(priv, offset);
        pages[i] = virt_to_page(data_buf);
        get_page(pages[i]);
        partial[i].offset = 0;
        partial[i].len = dsta_buf->bytes_xferred;
        total_sz += partial[i].len;
    }

    error = _splice_to_pipe(pipe, &spd);

    /* use the ppos to return the theory total bytes shoud transfer */
     *ppos = total_sz;

    return error;
}

/* splice read */
static ssize_t rdma_ring_splice_read(struct file *in, loff_t *ppos,
    struct pipe_inode_info *pipe, size_t len, unsigned int flags)
{
    ssize_t ret;

    MY_PRINT("%s: *ppos = %lld, len = %ld\n", __func__, *ppos, (long)len);

    if (unlikely(len > PIPE_DEF_BUFFERS))
        return -EINVAL;

    ret = do_rdma_ring_splice_read(in, ppos, pipe, len, flags);
    return ret;
}
```

The _splice_to_pipe is just the same one as the splice_to_pipe in kernel. As this function is not an exported symbol, so I re-implemented it.
I think the main cause is that the some kind of lock of pages are omitted, but
I don't know where and how.

My kernel version is 3.10.